# i am unable use bandclientmanager in windows run time

Tags: c#, microsoft-band

Developing `Microsoft Band SDK` use with Windows Runtime Component, if i add `BandClientManager` in my `WinRT` class it says this is does not exist
I unable to add this reference "`Microsoft.Band.Phone`" but `Microsoft.Band` and `Microsoft.Band.Store` are successfully referenced

Comment: Can you provide more information about the kind of Windows Runtime Component you're building?  Is it targeted at Windows Phone 8.1, Windows Store 8.1, or Windows 10 Universal?  Did you apply the Band SDK NuGet package to the project or are you referencing the assemblies individually?

The Microsoft.Band.Phone assembly would not be referenced by a Store or Universal component, for example, as it's specific to Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.Band SDK currently works only with Universal Windows Platform (and 8.x), so the Interface is available for you to use, but the implementation is not, that's why `BandClientManager` cannot be resolved.

Quoting @[Phil Hoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4272205/phil-hoff-msft)

> The BandClientManager type is specific to the platform on which the Band SDK is being used (e.g. Windows Phone or Windows Store), due (in part) to differences in the Bluetooth API between platforms. It's not portable so it cannot be used directly from a Portable Class Library that targets multiple platforms.

Instead, you need to limit your use of the Band SDK in your PCL to the IBandClientManager interface, which is portable. Then, your platform-specific library can inject the appropriate BandClientManager.Instance at runtime.